# Different versions of Python, packages and many terminals in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using Windows 7 and already installed Python version 3.8.10. After installing Anaconda 4.9.0, I open Jupyter Notebook and see that Python has a brother, version 3.8.3. Should I remove one?

Not only that, all Python packages in Jupyter have different versions than existing ones. I also find out now there are a lot more terminals: one is from drop-down "New", one is called Anaconda prompt and the last one is Anaconda Powershell prompt, not to mention the usual windows terminal.

Can anyone please give a simple explanation about this and please indicate which terminal should I use to install and upgrade packages for Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Been a while I used windows, but I'll tell you this. Anaconda is a suite of tools and you don't have to use everything. Anaconda prompt and Anaconda Powershell are basically the same, it's just that the Anaconda prompt uses a Windows command prompt while the other uses a Windows Powershell as a base.

I'll say use the Anaconda prompt since it should feel more welcoming and easy to use.